# How to calculate the true coordinates of a point, whose position depends on the position of a reference point?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems, rotations, transformation

I have a point A, whose position I know in Cartesian coordinates x and y (referred to as *true coordinates*). I need to calculate the coordinates of point B, whose position is always set relative to point A. Point A has its own Cartesian coordinate system x'y' (referred to as *relative coordinates*), where y' shows its heading and is different from y.

The values of point B relative to point A depend on which quadrant of x'y' coordinate system it falls. For example, if point B is on the right and in front of point A, it will have positive values for x' and y'.

**Question:** How do I calculate the true coordinates of point B, if the true coordinates of point A are known and the relative coordinates of point B are known?

I found the following question, which is somehow related: [Calculate the new position of a point after rotating it around another point 2D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3935956/calculate-the-new-position-of-a-point-after-rotating-it-around-another-point-2d). [This website](https://www.math10.com/en/geometry/analytic-geometry/geometry1/coordinates-transformation.html) has useful information too.

[image]

Comment: Just add 1 to x and y to y

Comment: what i would suggest is to plug in some coordinates for x,y and for x',y' and take some time to calculate and/or draw out the results, you should see a pattern

Comment: @Moti I don't think that solves the question because there is also an angle difference between `y` and `y'`. So, if point A is rotated towards `x` axis, a x+1 i reference coordinates translates to y-1 in true coordinates.

Comment: Is the x'y' system always aligned with the xy system, or could it be at any angle? I notice in your diagram that the two systems have opposite [handedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Orientation_and_handedness)

Comment: If I correctly understood the question, the answer is $x_B=x_A+y'$, $y_B=y_A-x'$.

Comment: @Kristof I made an error - since this is a translation and "renaming of axis" just calculate B in the new coordinate and this difference could be used to map every point. Note that this is rotation and mirror.